# No space after macro

Tags: spacing, macros

I define a preamble as follows: `\newcommand\BuildingX{Building-X{}}\`

When I use the preamble in sentences like as follows:

```
First, \BuildingX provides ...
```

The output is "First, BuildingXprovides ..."

There is no space after 'BuildingX'. How can put a space there?

Comment: Put the `\ ` inside the braces. `\newcommand\BuildingX{Building-X\ }`

Comment: You might have a look at `\xspace` from the `xspace`-package.

Comment: @TeXnician -- if you put the space there, it will be in the output even if the command is followed directly by a period.  that is what the `xspace` package was created to solve.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I know, that was the quick-fix for the symptom. That's why I marked it as duplicate to have some more comprehensive answers.